# Screenshot using drawing cache and saving to file adds noise to image

Tags: android, file, save

I have multiple activities that each one apply some visual effects on screen then save and send it's uri to another activity,but after each process(getDrawingCache + save + send)some noises appear on image,this is my code:

```
    FrameLayout frame1=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.finalview_new);
            frame1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            frame1.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap=frame1.getDrawingCache();
             String fileName = "myImage";//no .png or .jpg needed
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = 
       new    ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                    FileOutputStream fo = 
       openFileOutput(fileName, aftertext.this.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    // remember close file output
                    fo.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    fileName = null;
                }
                ed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                onCreate(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the culprit

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

JPEG is a lossy format. Use the [BitmapFormat.PNG option instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.CompressFormat.html).